# iOS 7 Web Core issus loadPendingImages

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, cfnetwork

I have this crash log, but I don't understand how to find what causes an issue.

```
Thread : Crashed: WebThread
0  WebCore                        954995104 WebCore::StyleResolver::loadPendingImages() + 1135
1  WebCore                        955192507 WebCore::ResourceRequestBase::~ResourceRequestBase() + 106
2  WebCore                        954966933 WebCore::StyleResolver::applyMatchedProperties(WebCore::StyleResolver::MatchResult const&, WebCore::Element const*) + 792
3  WebCore                        955009301 WebCore::StyleResolver::styleForElement(WebCore::Element*, WebCore::RenderStyle*, WebCore::StyleSharingBehavior, WebCore::RuleMatchingBehavior, WebCore::RenderRegion*) + 952
4  WebCore                        956072077 WebCore::Document::styleForElementIgnoringPendingStylesheets(WebCore::Element*) + 96
5  WebCore                        956071899 WebCore::Element::computedStyle(WebCore::PseudoId) + 142
6  WebCore                        956433467 WebCore::ComputedStyleExtractor::propertyValue(WebCore::CSSPropertyID, WebCore::EUpdateLayout) const + 466
7  WebCore                        957126027 WebCore::CSSComputedStyleDeclaration::getPropertyValue(WebCore::CSSPropertyID) const + 42
8  WebCore                        957125931 WebCore::CSSComputedStyleDeclaration::getPropertyValue(WTF::String const&) + 26
9  WebCore                        957459107 WebCore::jsCSSStyleDeclarationPrototypeFunctionGetPropertyValue(JSC::ExecState*) + 258
10 JavaScriptCore                 838902235 llint_native_call_trampoline + 64
11 JavaScriptCore                 838939999 JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 70
12 WebCore                        955098071 WebCore::JSMainThreadExecState::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 146
13 WebCore                        957106929 WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*) + 520
14 WebCore                        956836797 WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>&) + 484
15 WebCore                        955783727 WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*) + 178
16 WebCore                        955784069 WebCore::EventContext::handleLocalEvents(WebCore::Event*) const + 60
17 WebCore                        955783067 WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatch() + 546
18 WebCore                        955782519 WebCore::EventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent(WebCore::EventDispatcher*) const + 10
19 WebCore                        955780731 WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::EventDispatchMediator>) + 154
20 WebCore                        955780413 WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 100
21 WebCore                        955830855 WebCore::Document::finishedParsing() + 102
22 WebCore                        955791991 WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::prepareToStopParsing() + 122
23 WebCore                        956118393 WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::notifyFinished(WebCore::CachedResource*) + 68
24 WebCore                        956102527 WebCore::CachedResource::checkNotify() + 42
25 WebCore                        956102065 WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didFinishLoading(double) + 112
26 WebCore                        956101909 WebCore::didFinishLoading(_CFURLConnection*, void const*) + 132
27 CFNetwork                      818745231 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 74
28 CFNetwork                      818740111 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 54
29 CFNetwork                      818942775 ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 18
30 CoreFoundation                 821665441 CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
31 CFNetwork                      818314757 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 164
32 CFNetwork                      818314453 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 220
33 CFNetwork                      818314085 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 48
34 CoreFoundation                 822288159 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
35 CoreFoundation                 822285287 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
36 CoreFoundation                 822279127 __CFRunLoopRun + 630
37 CoreFoundation                 821666929 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
38 CoreFoundation                 821666387 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
39 WebCore                        955674821 RunWebThread(void*) + 420
40 libsystem_pthread.dylib        1000184925 _pthread_body + 140
41 libsystem_pthread.dylib        1000184783 _pthread_start + 102
42 libsystem_pthread.dylib        1000176848 thread_start + 8
```